Beliefs and memories from Inside Out 2, our sense of self
In the movie, “Inside Out 2”, it was revealed that Riley’s memories contributed to her belief system and sense of self. This is pretty much in line with existing research into how memory define our beliefs and identity. However, it also begs a few questions.
First, how do we prevent wrong memories from forming that create unskilful beliefs or views? Or correct our interpretation of such memories if they are already formed? I am especially intrigued by wrong beliefs (or views) that are formed from bad memories. Like in Riley’s case, “I’m not good enough” partly from her anxiety and self-critique but triggered by recalled images of how she almost failed her hockey team. (Of course, there are skilful/wholesome beliefs too like, “I’m a good person” when Riley recalled images of making all sorts of friends while growing up).
Second, it appears that extremism, intolerance and prejudices arise from wrong beliefs. Yet, tapping on our reservoir of diverse memories and beliefs can pull us out of difficult situations. Such as when Riley was suffering from a panic attack in the penalty box, drawing on all her memories, experiences and beliefs to restore a correct sense of herself. This is possible because she had a myriad and diverse memories/experiences growing up. So, does this mean that having a variegated memory/experience from interacting with various different types of people, beliefs, views and ideologies would be helpful in reducing extremism, intolerance and prejudices? Does this mean that Buddhists should not associate solely with Buddhists and should expose themselves to other religious teachings like the Bible, Koran, Vedas and so on. Ditto for Christians, Muslims, Hindus and so on? (Note: the Buddha himself was exposed to a wide variety of ideologies/belief systems in his search for liberation).
Third, can the Dharma be extreme or lead to extreme, intolerant and prejudiced behaviour? Or does it instead have a moderating effect?
Lastly, it seems that the process of memory consists of 3 stages: encoding, storage and retrieval. I suspect mindfulness practice can help with the storage and retrieval stage, is this correct? Are there any Buddhist practices that can help with the encoding stage? As I suspect existing biases/prejudices could prevent objective encoding. Similarly, wrong interpretation of our memories could also cause issues as research into cognitive and memory biases indicated. All these could result in errors in decision making, wrong views/beliefs and ultimately suffering. Is there any Buddhist practice to overcome biased interpretation?

First, how do we prevent wrong memories from forming that create unskilful beliefs or views?
Perhaps that's primarily the teacher's or parent's job.
Like in Riley’s case, “I’m not good enough” partly from her anxiety and self-critique but triggered by recalled images of how she almost failed her hockey team.
I won't see the movie -- nor the links to literature that you posted.
I notice that in this example, "being good enough" depends on outcome ("failing the team"). Instead you might be taught that it depends on process -- i.e. whether you try, whether you play, not whether you win.
For example, it doesn't matter how well I passed some arithmetic test back in grade 2 ("outcome") -- what matters is whether I learned to learn what was being taught in class ("process").
Are there any Buddhist practices that can help with the encoding stage?
Probably. When "a thought arises" then do you accept it? For example, this thought might arise:

"I haven't heard from my boss, he's ignoring me, he probably doesn't like me"

This might be a way to "not accept" that thought:

"No, that's a self-pitying/self-view kind of thought -- it's more likely that he's busy doing other things."

I'm not sure how exactly that's "Buddhist" i.e. mentioned in the suttas. I suppose it's part of the general idea of choosing skilfully in order to avoid unnecessary suffering.

+1 for the reminder on focusing on the process and the example on handling an unskilful thought, these insights would be helpful to anyone. I think the movie is good....although it may not be to everyone's taste.

The penultimate line of one of the 101 Zen Stories advises, "Live with cause and leave results to the great law of the universe."

You have a wrong grasp of memories. Memories are not stored or retrieved. Memories are a result of combination. Memories are impermanent. They are arise , change and vanish. Because memories are impermanent, they are source of suffering. Therefore memories are not self. It is invalid to say that I did this , I did that, or this happened to me or that happened to me or this is what I am doing or this is what is happening to me.
In short , do not attach to memories , whether good or bad, as Self.
However it is easier said than done. Practice compassion to overcome bad memories. Be blameless. Do whatever to get rid of the bad feelings related to bad memories. Practice meditation. Develop thoughts of renunciation. These efforts will dilute your attachments to past. And for future do not accept any kind of becoming because all becoming results in suffering.
Be an extremist in the Buddhist sense. Give up all kinds of attachments.
Practicing Dhamma makes you extremely benevolent to all. So practice it properly. Do not develop wrong notions of Self.

+1 for using compassion to overcome bad memories and renunciation to dilute past attachments. Can I clarify what do you mean by Memories are a result of combination?

@Desmon here is an example of combination : when eye consciousness, eye and scenery come in contact then memories are available . Or when mind consciousness, mind and object of mind come in contact then memories are available.

Of course memories are stored and retrieved, that's just a basic fact. The word "remember" means to retrieve stored memories. It's the foundation of Buddhist practice, and life in general, because without being able to remember the Teachings, you'd have no way to put them into practice. Anything with a brain stores and retrieves memories.

@Dan I am not denying memory. I am denying that memory is stored anywhere. When combinations arise memories arise like waves.

There is no wrong memory, unless you depict it wrongly, ie., you tell a false narrative to yourself about the memory. Effectively, your memory is an impression of a past impression.  That's how I understand it. Then you can react to that arisen entity however you like, but given that it corresponds to a past impression, you will suffer the bias it entails.

He hears Dhamma as it is being taught by the Tathāgata or by a
disciple of the Tathāgata for rooting out all resolve for, bias,
tendency and addiction to view and causal relation, for tranquillising
all the activities, for casting away all attachment, for the
destruction of craving, for dispassion, stopping, nibbāna

Parable of Water Snake

+1 for pointing out that memory is an impression of a past impression. Indeed, research had shown its fragility and malleability.

BTW, the link is not working.

here is says, "As a person’s knowledge so is his memory." the way we remember things is according to our knowledge

Memory forms the foundation of knowledge and prior knowledge in turn influences the way our memory are formed, interesting!!
